# How to recover aws ElasticSearch Cluster status is Red and cannot access it

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

My AWS ElasticSearch cluster health goes to Red and I cannot access it, and it always show

```
<html>
<head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know how to recover it? I've made manually backup every day but problem is whenever I access with `CURL`, it always return to 502 results.

```
curl -XGET 'https://xxxx2.es.amazonaws.com/_snapshot?pretty'
```

It always return 502 because my cluster goes to Red.

Comment: were you able to solve this?

Comment: @PabloCG that's out of space issue. I needed to increase storage.

Comment: @PPShein Would you kindly consider posting your solution as an answer and then accepting it, as this is technically an Answered Question now? Because it would help to clear the clutter in Unanswered Questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JVM memory pressure is building up due to out of space issue. And it was working when I've increased storage size and add new node as well.